# Displaying custom (personally created) Unicode characters on a site

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, customization, non-ascii-characters

Let's say I created a shorthand writing system with its own custom set of unique characters that don't exist in Unicode.

Is there a way that I could:

- personally draw each character,
- then assign each character its own code in Unicode,
- then write those codes in an HTML page,
- then publish that HTML page on a site,
- and then somehow enable other people to actually view those unique characters when they visit that site's page?

Comment: You could put the characters in a [private use area](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) and supply your own font that defines them however you like.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, but how would I "define" (for lack of a better word) it as my own font, and then how could I reference/enable other people to view that font?

Comment: You should research those as separate questions: how to create a custom font, and how to supply a font with your website.